# How do I enable Compiz in xubuntu?

Tags: 11.04, compiz, xubuntu

I would like to use Compiz in Xubuntu (under xfce obviously).

I have seen this tutorial: http://www.ghacks.net/2010/07/11/run-compiz-with-xfce4/

Firstly, this didn't work well for me, because when trying `compiz –replace ccp &` in a terminal, it tells me there is no plugin such as cpp, and the window decorations are lost right away.

Is there a reliable way to run Compiz with XFCE, please? I miss my desktop cube.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the answers so far. Just running `compiz --replace` still causes the complete loss of window decorations.

Also, I tried fossfreedom's suggestion, and then I get the output below. I installed emerald initially because it was complaining about not finding it, but I think I had the segfault even without emerald.

```
(some other output)
...
/usr/bin/emerald: Screen 0 on display ":0.0" already has a decoration manager; try using the --replace option to replace the current decoration manager.
Segmentation fault
Setting Update "command"
```

**UPDATE 2**

Well, turns out that just trying to run emerald by itself ends with a segfault, and apparently this is a known bug. Used the solution here to resolve that problem: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/get-emerald-to-work-in-ubuntu-1104.html

Still, I wasn't actually hoping to use Emerald, but what the heck.

Comment: I removed emerald, and now it just complains about not finding it (no segfault after all), but still no window decorations.

Comment: I've repeated your segfault with emerald - however I can remove it successfully, logout and login and rerun the compiz command successfully.  Can you do `unity-window-decorator --replace &` - this should work if you have install compiz-gnome package (installed automatically with the packages in my answer)

Comment: Well, I noticed that running emerald --replace by itself also ends with a segfault. Turns out it's a known bug. Will update my question quickly.

Comment: Can you add your update as an answer and mark this as answered?

Comment: I most certainly can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, turns out that just trying to run emerald by itself ends with a segfault, and apparently this is a known bug.

Solution:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:malteworld/compiz
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

[source](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/get-emerald-to-work-in-ubuntu-1104.html)

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz gnome-themes compizconfig-settings-manager
compiz --replace ccp &
```

If there are any errors displayed in the terminal, please add the output into your question.

Comment: Package gnome-themes is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gnome-themes' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 2):

ccp is a name of a plugin. If you don't have it installed, then you can't load it. Try compiz --replace instead.

Also, if you run compiz that way, you should use the nohup command. Otherwise, when you close the terminal, compiz will also be closed. So instead, you'll write:

nohup compiz --replace

Try this and provide some feedback. If it doesn't work, then we'll have another look at it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You might check that window decoration is enabled in Compiz.  Run "ccsm" (the Compiz config manager, which should also show up in a menu somewhere).

In the 'Effects' section, the "Window Decoration" feature should be checked.
Click the "Window Decoration" box and it's settings appear; in there, the decorator command can be specified.  I've read somewhere that some window decorators won't work with compiz, but gtk-window-decorator and compiz-decorator do.   Good luck!