# Is Compiz compatible with Xfce?

Tags: compiz, xfce, compatibility, xubuntu

I tried it and immediately had a big problem ([here](https://askubuntu.com/q/114600/47206)). Also, could not use more than one workspace.  It is said that they are compatible, that is: I can install Compiz with Xfce if I want to. But I enter a world of bugs, am I not?

I would like more opinions, please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Compiz is compatible with XFCE. The thing is, for common people, choosing XFCE over the "common" ones like KDE, Unity and Gnome is because of limited resources (CPU and Memory most of the time).

But sources like the following confirm that Compiz is compatible with XFCE but needs a little more loving to get it working:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compiz#XFCE
- http://www.ghacks.net/2010/07/11/run-compiz-with-xfce4/
- [How do I enable Compiz in xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58002/how-do-i-enable-compiz-in-xubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

XFCE is for users that want a minimalist desktop.  Saying I want to use XFCE and I want to use Compiz is a lot like saying I want apple juice, but it should taste like orange juice.  I use XFCE, but I don't complain about the 3D buggy-ness.

Comment: i agree. i was just curious to see compiz at work, not using it necessarily. it didnt't seem to work ok. i like minimalist every day except on tuesdays.

Comment: I disagree. The reason is simple: tearing. The "3D buggy-ness" in turn solves this problem and it has nothing to do with "minimalistic" outlook (which I prefer, too).

Comment: @avp If you're just trying to fix screen tearing, use compton. It's a very lightweight compositor that works beautifully. Much more effective than Compiz if you don't need Compiz's large feature set.

Comment: @alanaktion thanks for bothering. I've already found the best of two worlds. It is elementary.io (I am not sure, but I think they use Gala, the Mutter-based WM).

Comment: If you're still looking light but nice compositing LXQt is coming to LXDE main soon.  I like it with kwin WM.

Comment: What about moving to Xfce because Unity has spyware and is ridden by bugs and crashes ever since its creation? That was my main reason I changed DE, not the lack of resources; so if I can afford the eye candy, why not use Compiz? Plus this reply doesn't answer the question and imho sounds a bit aggressive.

Comment: Just turn off zeitgeist.  It's the thing that tracks activity for unity.  Also, Unity is sort of dead.  They're taking mainline back to gnome3

Comment: Never tell users they're "wrong" for wanting what they want. I have eye disabilities and make EXTENSIVE use of "invert" both screen and individual windows--which compiz provides.