# how to obtain same original workspace-switcher when using XFCE? using ubuntu 11.10

Tags: xfce

I installed 11.10 to try it. Started with the default desktop (I think it is called the GNOME SHELL), which is like this image shows

http://iloveubuntu.net/ubuntu-1110s-workspace-switcher-features-new-fancy-behavior

Now I installed xfce to try it, using this command:

```
sudo aptitude install xubuntu-desktop
```

and logged out and then selected xfce session (I also saw xubuntu session there to select, was not sure, but for now I use xfce). Then I login

my question is: I really liked the workspace-switcher on default desktop before. Because I can click on it, and see all 4 desktops at once, so I can more easily move windows from one to another by just dragging it, and can see more easily which one I can to go to. like the image above shows.

Now with xfce, I have to select a window, right click, say move to this workspace, etc..., which is not as easy to do as before.

Is there a way to do something like this on xfce? I see on the panel at the top of xfce the 4 virtual desktops, but I like to see them like with the original desktop, all at once on the desktop.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

That screenshot is of Unity, not Gnome Shell and the functionality you want is provided by compiz, the compositing window manager that Unity uses, it is possible to use compiz in xfce, i refer you to this very similar question:

[Is Compiz compatible with Xfce ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114613/is-compiz-compatible-with-xfce)

Hope this helps. ;)

Comment: I saw compiz before, but all what I saw was 3D stuff. I really do not want all that. All what I want is what I have in the default 11.10 desktop, which splits the screen into 4 quadrants, each showing small scale of each virtual desktop in each quarter f the monitor allowing me to easily drag windows from one to another and see what is inside the virtual desktop. But I will look now more at compiz again, may it I missed something.

Comment: @RobertH Compiz provides that functionality as a plugin, you can disable most of the other 3D stuff if you wish, they are all just plugins.